# delay in executing widget program

Tags: c++, qt

I have a **Main** window with push buttons to open other windows, as shown below:

[image]

Here both in **Program** window and **Logs** window , I have a ***back to main*** button which can take to the **Main** window.

In the **Logs** window at present I'm having a real-time display of sensor.

Everything seems fine if I start **Logs** from **Main** in the first time

But, if I goto **Programs**  -> *back to* **Main** -> **Logs** the Logs window is getting too much delayed.

This is how I go back to **Main** from **Program**

```
void stageProgram::on_pushButton_shoulderControl_clicked()
{

    this-> close();
    StageOneMain *newPatient = new StageOneMain(pLabel);
    newPatient-> show();
}
```

**Logs** from **Main**

```
void StageOneMain::on_pushButton_logs_clicked()
{
    this->close();
    window = new ShoulderControl(pLabel);
    window -> show();
}
```

Anybody see some issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use QStackedWidget. It is good for navigating through different "pages". You can add 5 pages to the stacked widget. when you click on a button and need to change to the respective page you do 
`stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(indexOfThePage);`
for example, the function to go back to main menu can look like
`stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);`
for further reference you can see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) page of the official Qt documentation.